# eclipse-maven- OpenIMAJ

Tags: java, openimaj

I want to index videos. So, first I have captured audio from a video using xuggle and openIMAJ libraries. Now, I have the audio in xuggle audio format.
How do I convert the audio to text?
I also need the text along with its corresponding time.

```
public class App {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Video<MBFImage> video;
        try {
            XuggleAudio xa  = new XuggleAudio(new File("tt.mp4"));
            AudioPlayer.createAudioPlayer( xa ).run();

            // VideoDisplay<MBFImage> display = VideoDisplay.createVideoDisplay(video);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( "no video" );
        }
   }
}
```